# How can I store the result of a find_by_sql(SUM(field)) into a variable?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have a sql query that I would like to capture. Here is the query:

```
sl = SlocMetric.find_by_sql("select sum(code_added), 
     sum(comments_added), sum(blanks_added), sum(code_removed), 
     sum(comments_removed), sum(blanks_removed) from sloc_metrics
       inner join diffs on diffs.id = sloc_metrics.diff_id 
       inner join commits on commits.id = diffs.commit_id 
    where commits.id = '499848202'")
```

The output of this query in actual SQL would give me a table of four sum values like so:

```
sum| sum| sum| sum|
1     23   43   34
```

Is there a way I can capture these values without absolutely having to use ActiveRecord. I know that there is a `.sum` method but in order to use this, I have to really modift the query in ActiveRecord and/or maybe use Arel which I really don't want to use. Help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give a name to each `sum`, i.e:

```
sl = SlocMetric.find_by_sql("select sum(code_added) as sum_1, 
     sum(comments_added) as sum_2, sum(blanks_added) as sum_3, sum(code_removed) as sum_4, 
     sum(comments_removed) as sum_5, sum(blanks_removed) as sum_6 from sloc_metrics
       inner join diffs on diffs.id = sloc_metrics.diff_id 
       inner join commits on commits.id = diffs.commit_id 
    where commits.id = '499848202'")
```

The result is an array of `SlocMetric` objects, and then you should be able to access it in each element, such as:

```
sl[0].sum_1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_rows()`, which will give you back an array of arrays, where each row is represented by an array with the `SELECT` values. For example, in your case you will do:

```
sl = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_rows("select sum(code_added), 
     sum(comments_added), sum(blanks_added), sum(code_removed), 
     sum(comments_removed), sum(blanks_removed) from sloc_metrics
       inner join diffs on diffs.id = sloc_metrics.diff_id 
       inner join commits on commits.id = diffs.commit_id 
    where commits.id = '499848202'")
```

And the output will be:

```
#=> [[1, 23, 43, 34]]
```

Now you can access the values with `s1[0]`, since your query only outputs one row:

```
sl[0].inspect
#=> "[1, 23, 43, 34]"
```